# aspnetboilerplate issues: asp.NET core template Web app issue

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have downloaded the asp.net core template from the below location but I am missing most of the JS files here-

downloaded location - https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnet-core-template

When I invoke the Web API swagger and it works fine without any issue but when I run the web app I am missing most of the JS & CS files as shown below-

There is no libs folder...Is there something missing?

```
    <script src="~/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/spin/spin.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs-ext/spin/jquery.spin.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/toastr/toastr.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/push.js/push.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/moment/moment-with-locales.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.jquery.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.toastr.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.blockUI.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.spin.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.sweet-alert.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/dataTables.buttons.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/libs/datatables/js/buttons.bootstrap4.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/abp.dataTable.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but incase someone else needs help.
First install `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.CLI`

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.CLI
```

and run

```
libman restore
```

from the Mvc folder

Comment: Could also right click on libman.json and select Restore Client Side Libraries.